# Does $\mathrm{Sym}(K_X)$ necessarily equal $\mathrm{Sym}(X)$?

Tags: group-theory

**Definition.** Whenever $H$ is a graph with underlying set $X$, write $\mathrm{Sym}\,H$ for the subgroup of $\mathrm{Sym}\,X$ generated by precisely those 2-cycles that permute adjacent elements of $H$.

Notice that (claim) if $H$ is a connected graph, it follows that $\mathrm{Sym}(H) = \mathrm{Sym}(K_X),$ where $K_X$ is the [complete graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_graph) on $X$.

**Question.** If $X$ is a finite set, does $\mathrm{Sym}(K_X)$ necessarily equal $\mathrm{Sym}(X)$?

*Proof sketch of claim.* Suppose $x,y \in X$. Then $H$ has a path from $x$ to $y$. Now permute $x$ along that path until we get to $y$, and then permute $y$ all the way back. This returns all elements to where they started, except for $x$ and $y$ which have swapped places.

Comment: Are you asking if the symmetric group is generated by its 2-cycles? [ Yes, it is. ]

Comment: @JackSchmidt, yeah. Link? (I just added a finiteness condition, since otherwise the answer is clearly "no").

Comment: http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Transpositions_generate_the_finitary_symmetric_group#Proof_for_a_finite_set

Comment: @JackSchmidt, thanks, all is clear now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is a yes.  Given a set $S$ of 2-cycles from a set $\operatorname{Sym}(X)$, the graph $H$ that you mention which represents this set of 2-cycles is called the transposition graph of $S$.  It can be shown that the permutation group generated by a set of 2-cycles is equal to $\operatorname{Sym}(X)$ if and only if the corresponding transposition graph $H$ is connected. Since a complete graph $K_X$ is connected, it follows that $\operatorname{Sym}(K_X)$ equals $\operatorname{Sym}(X)$.